# What would be the consequences of asymptotic freedom and color confinement of QCD for neutron stars?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-chromodynamics, neutron-stars, states-of-matter

Neutron stars are conjectured to have densities between $10^{14}$ and $10^{17}\ \text{g/cm}^3$. In the latter limit, the neutrons could be so close that the interaction between them would not be the *residual strong nuclear force* mediated by mesons, but perhaps there could be direct interaction between the quarks of different neutrons, right?

I wonder, if phenomena of quark and gluon physics like asymptotic freedom or color confinement could play some role in the macrostate of neutron stars?

Comment: It is stated by some physicists that in neutron stars, at densities of the order $10^{15}\ g\ cm^{-3}$ or greater, we have what is called a [quark-gluon plasma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma). This is a state of matter where we have an interacting ensemble of quarks and gluons at thermal equilibrium. Quark-gluon plasmas have also been produced at the LHC in about the year 2000.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_star

Comment: The deconfinement and asymptotic freedom phenomena at enormous neutron star densities are quite possibly of critical importance.  However, their exact effects are not well understood at all.  Deconfinement sets in a a scale at which the QCD coupling constant is still fairly large, and that means that you have a many-body system with fairly strong and rather complicated interactions.  That makes calculations tricky, at best.